# Java library for HTML analysis

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

(I've seen similar questions, but I think none of them cater to my specific needs, hence...)

I would like to know if there is a Java library for analysis of real-world (read: incomplete, ill-formed) HTML. By analysis, I mean things like:

- figuring out the most prominent color in an HTML chunk
- changing that color to some other color (hence, has to support modification of the HTML as well)
- pruning out unwanted tags
- fixing up the HTML to result in a well formed HTML snippet

Parts of the last two are done by libraries such as Jericho, and jTidy. 'Plugins' on top of these would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, after some analysis it seems what I've asked for in the first bullet above is not readily available :(

Have to think of some slick algorithm for this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check out TagSoup:

http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/

Comment: None of the libraries offer semantic analysis much. But voted for this as Tagsoup is really impressive nevertheless

Answer (score 2):

Well I would tidy it first into valid XML, then using XSLT do a conditional deep copy where I would do the most-prominent-color/pruning/whatever processing you need.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/), a Java port of [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/). It will, depending on what options you choose, fix non-well-formed HTML and otherwise clean it up.

You'll need something else for the colour changing stuff.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of jTidy. I was looking for something that can do some more semantic analysis on an HTML fragment

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find something in [this list](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers) (try TagSoup, NekoHTML, VietSpider HTMLParser).