# A HTML validator in Java

Tags: java, html

I want validate HTML code in Java.

Like this:

```
HTMLValidator.validateHTML("aaa<b>bbb<b>");
// Returns false, because tag <b> is not closed
```

What Java libraries exist to do this?

Comment: This question is closed and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144966/java-library-for-html-analysis is open - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers was of course closed but where is a current list of HTML Parser libraries for java now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098114/how-to-validate-html-matches-w3c-standards is another question along these lines that is open. Since there is quite a bit of interest I'd like to edit this question to get it reopened. With 2000 reputation I can edit it but not do the reopen request.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try JTidy.
JTidy is a Java port of HTML Tidy, a HTML syntax checker and pretty printer.

http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/