# How to assert for valid HTML per jUnit

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea, assert

I have a junit test that I need to validate for valid html.

Is there an assertValidHtml() or will I have to use something like jsoup then validate on that return value?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217801/a-html-validator-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Junit does not include an HTML parser or validator by itself. So yes, use something like jsoup to parse and validate your html and then do asserts on the result.